# Create a file for CRUD functions (With no plugin)

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

i want to add some tables to the wordpress main database and generate some html code with them.

for example: create table images, then add some pics to it and finally, generate a photo gallery

i want to create a page for (edit/delete/add/update) this gallery and only admin can do this job

i want to create a file for such things especially working with database

what is the best way to implement this? i mean, i want to do them manually with no plugin and just by my own codes

Comment: Have you done this before in a non wordpress environment? It's running php and sql, so the process would be just the same as any php and sql set up.

Comment: yes, i do, and i find the way, tnx

Answer (score 0):

If the feature you are trying to implement is for a specific theme, you would want to place your code in the functions.php of that theme.

If the feature you are trying to implement can be re-used across different themes, you will want to create a wordpress plugin, and look into the hooks for activation and deactivation of a theme.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

Comment: I would suggest NOT doing it in the themes functions.php as when they upgrade, you'll lose everything... Create a child theme and put your functions in that functions.php. This way you won't lose anything across theme/plugin upgrades.

Comment: g19fanatic, you are absolutely correct if the site is using a theme created by another author. If the theme is completely built in house, there should be no issue at all.